# Как изменить язык системы в windows программно?

Tags: windows, c++

Система windows server 2008 rc2

Вызовы

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
setlocale( LC_ALL, "ru_RU.CP1251" );
std::system("chcp 1251");

не прокатывают
```

Функция GetACP() (из winnls.h) возвращает 1252, а должна 1251.

Если вручную изменить язык системы
Панель управления - Часы, язык и регион - язык и региональные стандарты - дополнительно - язык программ не поддерживающих юникод.

на русский то
GetACP() возвращает 1251.

1. Есть ли возможность это сделать?
2. Можно ли это сделать без подключения не стандартных библиотек?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. 

У меня в Windows 7 вообще - после установки стоит русский. Так чтобы заработало, надо сначала по указанной Вами процедуре сменить его (менял на US), а потом опять сменить на русский.

Сначала (когда первый раз поставил семерку) я подумал, что просто где-то "начудил", однако при следующих установках пришлось делать то же самое.

Интересно, у всех так?

Comment: То есть получается как. 
Запуская допустим на турецкой windows с турецкой локалью.

std::string file_name = "файл.txt";
Скомпилированный код выглядит как бы так
std::string file_name = 80 42 18 96 121 45 67; // коды символов
std::wstring file_name = 1801 1423; // юникод

Дальше в соответствии с настройками локали, fstream принимая file_name сообщает системе, что кодировка турецкая. А на диске файл на русском. 

А раз в unix это работает, значит вероятно некоторые сложности есть именно в windows? И setlocale по идее должна корректно выполняться?
Отсюда выходит, что никак это не исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Changing Non-Unicode programmatically to Russian](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/106833/Changing-Non-Unicode-programmatically-to-Russian).

Вам нужна ф-ция `NtSetDefaultLocale`. Из доступного пользователю интерфейса библиотек Windows наиболее подходит [`SetLocaleInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374049.aspx), но по описанию она слишком слабовата будет для Вашей задачи =(

P.S. Нашел!
Попробуйте [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) с **`SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG`**. Никогда бы не догадался!!!

Comment: Т.е. я правильно понимаю, что желаемое поведение, чтобы ИМЕННО ДЛЯ ВАШЕЙ программы вызов `GetACP()` возвращал 1251, независимо от системных настроек?

Comment: Касательно перезагрузки - нет, необязательно. Всем окнам посылается специальное сообщение [WM_SETTINGCHANGE][1]. Так что в теории настройки могут изменяться и без перезагрузки.


  [1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx

Comment: Ээээээ. У меня другой вопрос. А зачем Вам менять значение, возвращаемое `GetACP()`? Проблема ведь в тех ф-циях, которые требуют задания какой-то кодовой страницы. Что мешает им задать то, что необходимо Вам? Можете привести примеры таких ф-ций, используемых в Вашей программе?

Comment: Ну вот самый простой пример.
Файл "файл.txt" будет открыт только в случаи если язык системы стоит русский.

    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

    int main()
    {
    std::system("chcp 1251");

    std::string file_name = "файл.txt";
    std::fstream file_read(file_name , std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if(!file_read)
    {
        std::cout << "\nошибка=" << file_read;
    }
        std::cout << "\nфайл открыт=" << file_name;
    }

Comment: У меня лично под g++ этот код вообще не собирается. Он требует правки. Как минимум - добавить заголовки `iostream` и `cstdlib`. Во-вторых, у меня съело `file_read(file_name...)`. Пришлось явно писать `file_name.c_str()`. Я просто не въезжаю. Если программируем под винду - что мешает использовать стандартные виндовые Unicode ф-ции? Все-таки стандартная библиотека C++ немного ущербна. Читать [тут][1]. Если нужен чистый (относительно) C++ решением может быть Boost.
 [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316672/opening-fstream-with-file-with-unicode-file-name-under-windows-using-non-msvc-co

Comment: Что касается ущербности стандартной библиотеки С++ относительно кодировок, то это немного не так. Не знаю, как в винде, но в лине сочетание установки нужных локалей с помощью std::setlocale и std::locale::global + wstring, wcout, wfstream и т.п. вопрос решают без проблем. Кроме того, можно для каждого файлового потока устанавливать свою локаль с помощью метода imbue

Comment: В С++2003 действительно конструктор файловых потоков не кушает std::string, но в С++11 уже кушает.

Comment: Да, это печально. :( 
Там рассуждают, что по простому это не сделаешь. 
Но говорят, что подобное должно быть исправлено в стандарте
C++11. 
Но я не очень понимаю где именно и как это исправлять. 

Попробовал везде использовать wstring wfstream. Это работает. 
Может имеет смысл ставить проверку на функцию GetACP()

if(GetACP() != 1251)
{
// использовать wfstream.
}
else
{
// использовать fstream.
}
??

Comment: А что именно должно быть исправлено в С++11 ?

Comment: Я просто повторил слух с предыдущей ссылки
"unfortunately there's no standard way to do that, although C++0x (1x?) promises to do that." 

Здесь ведь идет несоответствие кодировки имени файла на накопителе( UTF-16) и переменной std::string file_name = "файл.txt" так?

То есть той кодировки в которую преобразовывается константа "файл.txt"  перед тем как попасть в file_name?
Или я что то путаю? 
И это кодировка как раз и устанавливается языком системы?

Comment: Ну это да.